# Как сделать пульсирующую кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать круглую пульсирующую кнопку "позвонить" со значком трубки внутри, чтобы вокруг нее расходились волны и привлекали внимание?

```
<button type="button" class="phone_btn"><span class="phone_icon"></button>
```

Comment: Откройте сайт, где Вы это видели, и скопируйте решение. В одной из реализаций, я видел, что там несколько дивов, с бордер-радиусом, которым анимацией меняют размеры

Comment: Видел очень давно и сейчас уже не найти

Comment: не благодари [google](https://www.google.com/search?ei=3izTW6qMJsG8kwWhxKTADA&q=pulsed+button+animation+css+examples&oq=pulsed+button+animation+css+ex&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.33i21k1j33i160k1.1249.1728.0.2838.3.3.0.0.0.0.157.394.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.394...33i22i29i30k1.0.5Wj5cnEoPz8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одним из вариантов может быть Gif картинка(анимация).

Второй вариант это делать через анимации в CSS: создать несколько div через CSS оформить как кружки, задать различную прозрачность, после чего прописать им анимацию масштабирования через @keyframes

[Смотреть пример](https://codepen.io/bar2104/pen/MPLrVq)

```
#qwe{
  margin 50px;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius:50px;
  animation: mymove 1s infinite;

}

@keyframes mymove {
    from   {transform: scale( 1)}
    to {transform: scale(1.5)}
}
```

Comment: Покажите на примере

Comment: @ArturHan Добавил